# jQuery SerializeArray — How to exclude <select> with empty <opiton> value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, serialization

In my HTML form I have this part with `<select>`:

```html
 <form id="fruits">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="some_title"/>
  <select name="color">
    <option value="">all</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

And I serialise this form using `jQuery.serializeArray();`:

```js
var serialized_data = $("form#fruits").serializeArray();
```

Even when the first option with `value=""` is selected, it is serialised. So I get an Array like this:

```json
{"title":"some_title", "color":""}
```

But I need to get an Array like this:

```json
{"title":"some_title"}
```

Without `"color":""`

How to exclude this `<select>`, so that is is not being serialised?

P.S.
I've already tried things like:

```json
$("#fruits :input[value!='']").serializeArray();
```

and other answers on StackOverflow... id doesn't work with `.serializeArray();`!

Please give me the answer that really works and tell me the jQuery version which you use to test it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply disable it before serialize if its value is empty and then re-enable it

```js
$("#btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let $form = $('#form');
  let $select = $form.find('#select');
  if($select.val() === ''){
    $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  let value =  $form.serializeArray();
  $select.removeAttr('disabled');
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" checked name="check" />
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btn">Serialize and log</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Really cool not ordinary idea. I will use it if traditional way wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Finally only this solution works. Is there another way to define element #select. In your example $form.find('#select');  it is define by ID. But how to define all selects in this form  (all inputs with type=select)?

Comment: `.find("select").each(function(){if($(this).val() == ''){...`

Comment: Could you please write the full javascript. I don't get where should I pul the ")"  in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery filter where the object name doesn't equal color. This will give you an array without the color key/value.

```
var serialized_data = $("#fruits").serializeArray();

serialized_data = serialized_data.filter(function(objectElement){
    return objectElement.name != "color";
});
```

Comment: Actually, I have a lot of fields (not only "color"), and I want to exclude them all, if their value="'!

Comment: In that case you can add on to the 
`return objectElement.name != "color"; ` line such as 

`return objectElement.name != "color" && objectElement.name != "otherKey";`

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector in CSS which does this. Attribute selectors match attribute values, not input element values.

You would have to use JavaScript.

For example, after selecting the elements, you would filter them like this:

```
var filtered = $("selector for form elements").filter(function(){
    return this.value.trim() !== "";
});

//and now work on the filtered elements
$(filtered).serializeArray();
```

Comment: What should I put instead of "selector for form elements" ? $("form#fruits") ?

Comment: @yestema I'd use $("#fruits input, #fruits select, #fruits textarea")